# Multiple text fields refusing to load selected objects

Tags: python, textfield, maya

The code I made, despite double, triple, and quadruple checking is refusing to load selected items into the text fields, that is assuming you can get maya to get over it's newfound hatred of the cmds.windows function

The errors I'm getting are threefold, if you try to load the code into a new window you will just get

> Error: name 'window' is not defined" assuming you make it past that hurdle you will run into 2 problems: the first is just from pasting the code below. The menu will load just fine, but if you hit either "Load A Node" or "Load B Node" you will get the error "# Error: Object 'window1|columnLayout9|sld_surfaceTextHJ' not found.

I never put "sld_surfaceTextHJ" in the code, so I dont know why maya keeps asking for it. If you humor it however and try to change the name 'sld_surfaceTextA' or 'sld_surfaceTextB' to any other name you will get the third error: # Error: name 'window1|columnLayout9|sld_surfaceTextHJ' is not defined.

The script used to work fine loading selections, but it seems that every script I made following this format is refusing to work.

Here it is if you want to take a crack at it

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.window(window, exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI(window)

window = cmds.window(title='DS selection connector demo')
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

sld_textFldA = cmds.textField('sld_surfaceText1', width =240)
load_button = cmds.button( label='Load A Node', c = set_textfield)

sld_textFldB = cmds.textField('sld_surfaceText2', width =240)
load_button = cmds.button( label='Load B Node', c = set_textfield)

node_button = cmds.button( label='Connect Node', c = make_node)


def set_textfieldA(_):
    sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    cmds.textField(sld_textFldA, edit=True, text=sel[0])

def set_textfieldB(_):
    sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    cmds.textField(sld_textFldB, edit=True, text=sel[0])


def connect_node(_):
   text_value = cmds.textField(sld_textFldA, q = True, text=True)
   text_value = cmds.textField(sld_textFldB, q = True, text=True)
   if text_value:
       print "created:", cmds.connectAttr('transform', n=text_value +'_firstGuy')
       print "created:", cmds.connectAttr('transform', n=text_value +'_secondGuy')

   else:
       cmds.warning("select an object and add it to the window first!")

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

The expected results are rather simple: you hit "Load A Node" on any node you create to load the first Node, Then you hit "Load B Node" on the second node you created: then upon hitting "Connect Node" the translate attribute of your first node should be connected to your second node like the connection editor.

Comment: Would be great if we can see the GUI

Comment: @ycx what do you mean exactly? Is the pasted code not creating a dialogue window for you?

Comment: Impoved legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, for anyone interested: here is the fixed code, I still haven't gotten the connect attributes part figured out yet: but for anyone looking for a simple textField selection loader demo, here you go:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.window(window, exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI(window)

window = cmds.window(title='DS selection connector demo')
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

sld_textFldA = cmds.textField('sld_surfaceText1', width =240)
load_button = cmds.button( label='Load A Node', c = set_textfield1)

sld_textFldB = cmds.textField('sld_surfaceText2', width =240)
load_button = cmds.button( label='Load B Node', c = set_textfield2)


def set_textfield1(_):
    sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    cmds.textField(sld_textFldA, edit=True, text=sel[0])

def set_textfield2(_):
    sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    cmds.textField(sld_textFldB, edit=True, text=sel[0])


cmds.showWindow( window )
```

Comment: What seems to be a bit strange is that this code works at all for you. If I copy and paste it, it fails because you use the variable "window" before initializing it. So you should add window="" after the import line. And to avoid problems, it is always a good idea to avoid variable names which are command names. `window`is a maya command. In your case it is not a problem because you do not import it directly but only via the cmds module.

Comment: Hey @haggikrey, Sorry, I'm kindof new to the whole programming thing. If you dont mind me asking, what are variable and command names? My strategy so far has just been brute forcing to see what works, do you have any examples?

Comment: In the Maya help docs, under the **Technical Documentation** all the commands are listed. Variable names are simply the names you give your variable. So imagine you use a variable called `window` and instead of importing `maya.cmds as cmds` you use for some reason `from maya.cmds import window`. Then your script will fail because your variable called `window` will mask the command with the same name `window`. That's the reason why it is a good idea to try to use unique names.

Comment: Thank you @haggikrey, thanks to your advice I was able to figure out the "Window not defined" issue, I ran into a new (but insignificant) problem, the window opens: but now "widthHeight" wont resize the window

Comment: if cmds.window("dumWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("dumWin")

myWindow = cmds.window("dumWin",t='DS Node Connector demo', widthHeight =(300,200) )
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
cmds.showWindow(myWindow)